# Arch linux: CPU temprerature is -125°C (thinkpad x390)

Tags: arch-linux, thinkpad, temperature, sensors, fan

I had some problems with fans in my laptop so I tried to diagnose it. When I run `sensors` command I get this:

```
...

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +58.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +51.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +53.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:           0 RPM
CPU:         -125.0°C
GPU:           +1.0°C
temp3:         +4.0°C
temp4:        +65.0°C
temp5:       +121.0°C
temp6:       +121.0°C
temp7:        +17.0°C
temp8:        +66.0°C

...
```

(I removed irrelevant info from output)

I am confused about the `CPU: -125.0°C`. I would be less surprised if the temperature was `-127` but `-125` seems so random to me.

Another thing is that my fans are clearly running (very loudly) and `sensors` output still says `fan1: 0 rpm`.

How can I fix my sensors to work correctly so my fans will not run all the time ?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

lm-sensors supports a ton of monitoring chips however there are major caveats:

- In many cases support is reverse engineered and extracted data may not mean anything or is extracted incorrectly
- Some sensors may not be physically wired and could represent anything in the universe, including random data

`lm-sensors` allows to configure rules for your particular chip (`thinkpad-isa-0000`) using a configuration file in `/etc/sensors.d/anyname.conf`.

Arch Wiki has a nice overview of lm-sensors and how to configure everything: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/lm_sensors

The project itself has a ton of contributed files which is worth looking into: https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/tree/master/configs - if there's nothing for your laptop and you find out the proper rules to parse and show the data, please submit your config for others to use.

The standard configuration file (at least in Fedora) is in `/etc/sensors3.conf`. It's a good starting point.